# Doxygen in TCL missing @endcode tag

Tags: tcl, doxygen

I have the following TCL code, and I get an "reached end of comment while inside a @code block; check for missing @endcode tag!" in the blank line following "proc :: IniGuiValues { } {

The #\endcode is there after the closing brace of the proc. I do not understand why..

```
  ## For: Something
  # 
  # This proc initializes the GUI with meaningful values.
  # 
  # \arg \c PROC HAS NO ARGUMENTS.
  # \return PROC HAS NO RETURNVALUES
  # \todo Harmonize var names
  # \code
  proc ::IniGuiValues { } {
  THIS LINE IS BLANK
    set err [ catch { set LCIds [getSubcaseList] } res ]          
      if { $err == 0 } {
          set ::GUI_LCs $LCIds
      }
```

Comment: The end code doesn't appear in the sample you included in your question.  I find this an unusual use of the code command, what are you trying to do?

Comment: The #\endcode directly under the closing brace in reality. I want the whole code of this proc to show upp in the doc. Is that so unusual?

Comment: It's just that usually you use a code snippet in the comment itself rather than using the live code as the comment.  You're reaching the end of the doxygen comment block before you have your `endcode`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are breaking up the comment block before your endcode command.

```
## For: Something
# 
# This proc initializes the GUI with meaningful values.
# 
# \arg \c PROC HAS NO ARGUMENTS.
# \return PROC HAS NO RETURNVALUES
# \todo Harmonize var names
# \code
# proc ::IniGuiValues { } {
# THIS LINE IS BLANK
# set err [ catch { set LCIds [getSubcaseList] } res ]          
#   if { $err == 0 } {
#     set ::GUI_LCs $LCIds
#   } 
# \endcode
proc ::IniGuiValues { } {
THIS LINE IS BLANK
set err [ catch { set LCIds [getSubcaseList] } res ]          
  if { $err == 0 } {
      set ::GUI_LCs $LCIds
  }
```

Comment: Or, if you want to include the code in every output page, look at your Doxygen configuration.  http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/config.html#cfg_inline_sources

Comment: The inline_sources was what I needed. Funny though is that the way I tried it worked in some files but not in others.